# UWP: How to Retrieve Composite values from variables?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, uwp

I'm not a super experienced programmer so I may be asking sort of a dumb question, but I was making a to-do app. My app uses a really simple itemsControl that collects user input to create the item. Where I got stuck is trying tosave and serialize that data when the user exits the app. I can cache the data between pages, but if the user closes and reopens the app, the data is gone. I was trying to store the data in localSettings through a composite value, but I set the composites using pre-determined variables and I needed to be able to read that information later when I re-create the itemsControl with the saved information. Here's my code. I define variable for the itemsControl and the composite value here:

```
List<ToDoItem> items = new List<ToDoItem>();
    private void CreateItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        ToDoItemTemplate.Items.Add(new ToDoItem() { ItemTitle = NameBox.Text, Month = itemdate.Date.Month, Date = itemdate.Date.Day, Year = itemdate.Date.Year });
        Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;

        // Create a composite setting

        Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataCompositeValue composite = new Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataCompositeValue();
        composite["intValM"] = itemdate.Date.Month;
        composite["intValD"] = itemdate.Date.Day;
        composite["intValY"] = itemdate.Date.Year;
        composite["strVal"] = NameBox.Text;

        localSettings.Values["CompositeSetting"] = composite;
        addItemPopup.IsOpen = false;
        addItem.Background.SetValue(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty, Windows.UI.Colors.Transparent);
        NameBox.Text = "";
        CreateItem.IsEnabled = false;
    }
```

And I was *trying* to read the info from here. I have tried a lot of stuff and browsed through a lot of different forums already, including the official Microsoft Developer's site.

```
private new void Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
            Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataCompositeValue composite =
   (Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataCompositeValue)localSettings.Values["CompositeSetting"];

            if (composite == null)
            {
                // No data
            }
            else
            {
                ToDoItemTemplate.Items.Add(
                    new ToDoItem()
                    {
                        ItemTitle = "strVal",
                        Month = localSettings.Values["intValM"],
                        Date = localSettings.Values["intValD"],
                        Year = localSettings.Values["intValY"]
                    }
                );
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I formatted your code and now it can be seen what is the issue. :)

Where you create the new `ToDoItem` you use `localSettings.Values["intValM"]` etc.

You have your values in the `composite` variable, so you should write:

```cs
ToDoItemTemplate.Items.Add(
    new ToDoItem()
    {
        ItemTitle = composite["strVal"],
        Month = composite["intValM"],
        Date = composite["intValD"],
        Year = composite["intValY"]
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried to run the build with your suggestion but intellisense says "Cannot implicitly convert object to string." 'strVal' is supposed to be a string but somehow it appears as an object? I set it to Namebox.Text earlier. Should I first set Namebox.Text to a variable and set strVal to the variable from there?

Comment: Never mind, I used your suggestion and from there I fixed it myself by using the ToString method! Thanks so much! @Gabor

Answer (score 0):

> How to Retrieve Composite values from variables?

The code logic of your saving data into composite variable was correct. In `Loaded` event handler, you got the composite instance from localSettings, this step was right, but you got the specific values from localSettings was incorrect, you could get values from composite instance like the following code:

```
Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataCompositeValue composite =(Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataCompositeValue)localSettings.Values["CompositeSetting"];
if (composite == null)
{
}
else
{
    var ItemTitle = composite["strVal"];
    var Month = composite["intValM"];
    var Day = composite["intValD"];
    var Year = composite["intValY"];
}
```